# Java sleep only one object

Tags: java, timer, sleep

I have a program, where there are some dots flying on a screen. 
I need to do something where one dot is sleeping for 2 seconds.

```
public void move(Dot dot) {

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);                
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
fun();
}
```

Sleep cause the whole program stops for 2 seconds. How to do it for only one dot?

Comment: In your game loop, set the dot to sleep (a boolean which prevents Dot#move) and pass the time as well. If the time has passed set the boolean to false

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you're calling `sleep()` in your application-thread. If you do this your whole application is stopping for two seconds.

You could start a new [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) in which you're controlling your `dot`. Something like that:

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // control, move your dot or sleep here 
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change my `Dot` class to include a `Timer`. The `move` function could then decide based on some parameters if the `Timer` should be activated. Upon the first tick, disable the Timer. The `Timer` could set a `Boolean` which is queried when deciding whether moving the dot is allowed or not.

[Timer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your game looks something like this:

```
move(dot1);  // You want this to move instantly
move(dot2);  // You want this dot to sleep for 2 seconds, and then move
move(dot3);  // You want this dot to move instantly
```

The thing with program execution is that everything happens in order, one line of code after the other. So move(dot2) will only get executed once move(dot1) has finished, and move(dot3) will only get executed once move(dot2) has finished. In your example, you've changed move(dot2) to sleep for 2 seconds, which means that move(dot2) will only complete 2 seconds later, which means that move(dot3) will only start 2 seconds later, once move(dot2) has finished. In fact, because the entire rest-of-the-program only resumes once move(dot2) has finished, the entire program will sleep for 2 seconds like you mentioned.

**However**, there is exception to this. Everything mentioned above is only applicable for a *single thread*. Within a thread, all code will get executed sequentially, one after the other. However, if you create multiple threads, and give each thread a different piece of code to run, all the different threads will run in parallel. Even if Thread-A hits a piece of code that takes a long time to run (such as Thread.sleep(1000)), Thread-B will still be able to run its code without waiting around.

This is a powerful feature that can be applied to your game. You want move(dot2) to sleep for 2 seconds before moving, but you don't want the rest of the game to wait around for the 2 seconds. Solution: kick off a new thread, tell it to run move(dot2), and you main thread can immediately start executing the rest of your code.

Example:

```
move(dot1);  // will complete instantly
new Thread(() -> move(dot2, 2000)).start();  // Creates a new thread, tells it to execute move(dot2, 2000), and start it off
move(dot3);  // will complete instantly, as soon as move(dot2...) has been started off, without waiting for it to finish
```

[Some more details about Java multi-threading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

---

P.S. You mentioned a 2 second sleep, but your code is hard-coding the sleep to 1000ms, which is 1 second. If you want it to sleep for 2 seconds, you should change it to 2000ms.

Also, if you want some dots to move instantly and others to wait for 2 seconds, you should convert the 2000 into an input argument. That way, you can call move(dot1, 0) so that it will finish instantly, and move(dot2, 2000) so that it will finish after 2 seconds.